# By definition, can you believe in something that's not true?

Tags: meaning

Just wondering what people's thoughts are on this.

If something isn't true - can it be believed?

Comment: This is heavily discussed in philosophy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief#Justified_true_belief
Most people would argue that yes it can be.

Also related is Moore's Paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_paradox

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site.   You might want to try the Philosophy Stack Exchange site. http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about philosophy, not English language usage.

Comment: Sorry guys! Thought it would be more of a open and close question rather than a debatable topic!!

Comment: Yes, of course it can. Some people believe that God exists, others believe that God doesn't exist.  Those beliefs are contradictory so clearly one of those groups is believing in an untruth.

Comment: You *can* believe in something that's not true because the truth is often not dependent upon whether you accept it or not.  Sentences like "I believed in you!" indicating a newly formed mistrust; "If you believe that, you'll believe anything!" indicating gullibility and "Your beliefs are wrong." indicating disagreement all demonstrate instances where belief and the actual truth may be opposed. However the point of stating that you personally believe in something, is to convey that you think it is true with near if not absolute certainty, so the word should not be used lightly. Cogito ergo sum.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the OED defines 'believe' as `accept that (something) is true, especially without proof`, I would say `yes`.

Acceptance of truth does not make something true in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to believe something that's not true: such a belief might be called [a false belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_mind#False-belief_task).